# What type of syntax is being used in this declaration?

Tags: c++

```
SomeSmartPtr<MyObject> ptr(new MyObject());
ptr->DoSomething(); // Use the object in some way.
```

I'm just a c#/java person. What type of syntax is being used in the first line with the function call. Why is there not a declaration followed by the assignment operator. What allows you to assign and declare like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form of declaring and initializing an object is called direct initialization.

You can also use:

```
SomeSmartPtr<MyObject> ptr = new MyObject();
```

It is called copy initialization. You can read about the various types of initialization supported by C++ at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization.

Comment: "You can also use:" Not for most sane smart pointers. Allowing implicit conversion from a raw pointer to a smart pointer is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @T.C., for my benefit, do you have some references that delve into the subject?